# Azure find deployment name

Tags: azure

Im trying to shutdown a VM in Azure with this REST API:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157195.aspx

To make the call I need to know "cloudservice-name" and "deployment-name".
Where can I find these?
I cant find them anywhere on manage.windowsazure.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current portal (manage.windowsazure.com), when you create a Virtual Machine, a cloud service is created for you. To find the cloud service name, you would need to go to cloud services tab.

[image]

Click on the cloud service associated with your Virtual Machine and then go to dashboard. You will see the deployment name on the right hand side as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]